# Remove unwanted '[' and ']' in final output

Tags: python, list, output, counter, frequency

Hi so I'm writing a function that takes a files with text in it and returns the most common word in the file. My current code looks like this:

```
import collections

def approximate_song(filename):
    text = open(filename).read()
    counts = collections.Counter(text.lower().split())

return [elem for elem, _ in sorted(counts.most_common(), key=lambda
                                   x: (-x[1], x[0]))[:1]]
```

This returns the most common word. However, it returns it in the format ['word here'], when it should return it as 'word here'. (Not in square brackets, but just by itself in 's).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just access the first element, no? `[elem ... ][0]` is all you need.

Comment: Why not just `counts.most_common(1)[0][0]`? (maybe catching the `IndexError` if the list is empty).

Comment: It returns a list. If you want only the string, access the first element. Eg.,. LST[0] like @akshat mentioned..

Comment: What would that code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a list is represented with `[]`. For example, `[1,2,3,4,5]` is a list. In order to access individual elements, we use an index. So if `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` is a list, the first element can be accessed by `a[0]`, the second by `a[1]`and so forth.

Your code returns the entire list instead of the element. A simple modification of returning `[0]` element of the list achieves your objective.

```
import collections

def approximate_song(filename):
    text = open(filename).read()
    counts = collections.Counter(text.lower().split())

    return [elem for elem, _ in sorted(counts.most_common(), key=lambda
                                   x: (-x[1], x[0]))[:1]][0]

print(approximate_song('README.txt'))
```

Comment: Your code works, however, it fails on the input:
"Barbra Streisand
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Barbra Streisand
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo
Barbra Streisand

Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo

Comment: Barbra Streisand
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo

Barbra Streisand
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo
Barbra Streisand
Oo-oo oo-oo oo-oo whooo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo oo-oo oo-oo whooo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo

Comment: Barbra Streisand
Oo-oo whooo-oo
Oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo whooo-oo
Oo-oo whooo-oo
Barbra Streisand
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo
Oo-oo who-oo-oo whooo-oo oo-oo"

Comment: As it outputs: "oo-oo" instead of "whoo-oo"

Comment: Get rid of the `.lower()` from the code to get "whoo-oo". I just modified your code to remove the list. The reason why it does not work for the input you mentioned above is because if you convert everything to lower, "oo-oo" will match both "oo-oo" and also "whooo-oo"

Comment: ^That's not an edge case, that's a nightmare.

Comment: The code you have written is buggy, it works with the getting rid of `.lower()` modification for this input. However, it will not work if the 'oo-oo' is not differentiated from 'whooo-oo' with casing. I would suggest trying to figure this one out, as its a good exercise